# plotting sparce time with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a trading timeseries, e.g. close of 5 min bars. The markets are closed over night. So I have two queries:

How to plot time in MatPlotLib (as well as date). E.g. so I need to implement a new axis or new hourLocators etc.

How to remove overnight gaps from my plot. I.e. I want the last bar on Monday evening to be visually contiguous with the first bar of Tuesday morning. (Multiple plots won't work here as I need to display several days and pan the view.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/date_index_formatter.html).  It skips weekend gaps in a series of daily data and is very easy to adapt to your case.

Comment: How did you end up adapting this to skip overnights?

Comment: One point per five minute bar + custom label place where I wanted them.