# Skipping certain values in Python with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am currently working on an intra-day stock chart using the Alpha Vantage API. The data frame contains values from 4:00 to 20:00. In my matplotlib.pyplot chart however, the x-Axis also includes values from 20:00 to 4:00 over night. I dont want this as it messes up the aesthetics and also the Volume subplot.

Q: Is there any way to skip x-Axis values which dont exist in the actual Data Frame (the values from 20:00 to 04:00)?

[As you can see, the Data Frame clearly jumps from 20:00 to 04:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgAw.png)

[However in the Matplotlib chart, the x-Axis contains the values from 20:00 to 4:00, messing with the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsL6J.png)

Code so far. I believe so far everything is right:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import time
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Accessing and Preparing API
ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')

ticker_input = "TSLA"
interval_input = "15min"
df, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol = ticker_input, interval = interval_input, outputsize = 'full')
slice_date = 16*4*5
df = df[0:slice_date]
df = df.iloc[::-1]
df["100ma"] = df["4. close"].rolling(window = 50, min_periods = 0).mean()
df["Close"] = df["4. close"]
df["Date"] = df.index

#Plotting all as 2 different subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((7,1), (0,0), rowspan = 5, colspan = 1)
ax1.plot(df["Date"], df['Close'])
ax1.plot(df["Date"], df["100ma"], linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan = 2, colspan = 2, sharex = ax1)
ax2.bar(df["Date"], df["5. volume"])
ax2.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It would be great if anybody could help. Im still a complete beginner and only started Python 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641983/exclude-range-of-dates-in-matplotlib

Comment: The question is similar, but that one also doesn't have any answers. also the matplotlib site doesnt really help because that limits an exact y value. I want to skip it every time when it hits 20:00, whether it is 18-08-2020 20:00 or 25-12-2025 20:00. Therefore that solution doesnt really apply to mine

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085830/python-pandas-plot-time-series-with-gap

Comment: Also maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152396/plotting-sparce-time-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using matplotlib.ticker.formatter.

I first created a class and using:

```
class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, dates, fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'):
        self.dates = dates
        self.fmt = fmt

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        'Return the label for time x at position pos'
        ind = int(np.round(x))
    if ind >= len(self.dates) or ind < 0:
        return ''
    return self.dates[ind].strftime(self.fmt)

formatter = MyFormatter(df.index)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((7,1), (0,0), rowspan = 5, colspan = 1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax1.plot(np.arange(len(df)), df["Close"])
ax1.plot(np.arange(len(df)), df["100ma"], linewidth = 0.5)
ax1.xticks(rotation=45)
ax1.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan = 2, colspan = 2, sharex = ax1)
ax2.bar(np.arange(len(df)), df["5. volume"])

plt.show()
```

This gave me a smoother graph than the one before and also that recommended by r-beginner.
[image: THis is the result]

The only issue that I have is that if I zoom in the x-axis doesnt really change. it always has teh year, month, date, hour, and minute. Obviously I only want hour and minute when Im zoomed in further. I am yet to figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1):

We got the data from the same place, although the data acquisition method is different. After extracting it in 15 units, I created a graph by excluding the data after 8pm and before 4pm. I created the code with the understanding that your skip would open up the pause. What you want it to skip is skipped once the NaN is set.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import mplfinance as mpf
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('./alpha_vantage_api_key.txt') as f:
    api_key = f.read()

now_ = datetime.datetime.today()

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(now_.year, now_.month, now_.day - 1)

symbol = 'TSLA'
df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'av-intraday', start, end, api_key=api_key)

df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df["100ma"] = df["Close"].rolling(window = 50, min_periods = 0).mean()
df["Date"] = df.index
df_15 = df.asfreq('15min')
df_15 = df_15[(df_15.index.hour >= 4)&(df_15.index.hour <= 20) ]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.5),dpi=144)

#Plotting all as 2 different subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((7,1), (0,0), rowspan = 5, colspan = 1)
ax1.plot(df_15["Date"], df_15['Close'])
ax1.plot(df_15["Date"], df_15["100ma"], linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=20)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan = 2, colspan = 2, sharex = ax1)
ax2.bar(df_15["Date"], df_15["Volume"])
ax2.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]